# Android phones below a certain api level cannot see the play store listing

Tags: android, google-play

I have hosted my app on the Google Play Store. Most phones can go to the store and download it successfully. Certain phones can not see the listing, these phones are running Android 2.3.6.
I've a feeling that the target api in the manifest may have something to do with it?

This is what i have in my manifest.

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

.

All the phones on 4.x are fine.

Why can't lower Android phones see the listing?

Thanks.

[edit]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.carefreegroup.rr3"
    android:versionCode="24"
    android:versionName="3.0.2"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly" 
     >


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="11"
         />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" /> -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.carefreegroup.rr3.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.carefreegroup.rr3.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="true" />

        <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PREVENT_POWER_KEY" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />



    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />

    <!-- Donut-specific flags which allow us to run on any dpi screens. -->
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".NfcScannerApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"
        android:debuggable = "false" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name=".NfcscannerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"

            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.carefreegroup.rr3.QRCODE_ACTION" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".EntryActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".LoadTransactionsMap" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ViewTransactions"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".LoginValidate"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ViewTransactionsTest"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />

        <activity
            android:name=".NfcBaseActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />



        <activity android:name=".CaptureActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.carefreegroup.rr3.SCAN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ViewQrCodes"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ValidateUser"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ReportSomething"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GetClientDirections"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ViewPhoneNumbers"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GetRota"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GetRotaDetails"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ShowMoreDetails"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ReplyToMessageActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ViewMessagesActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".SendStandaloneMessageActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RecordActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>



        <activity
            android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MessageRecipientActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>


       <activity
            android:name=".CachedRotaActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".EmailLog"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>


       <service android:name=".SendOutstandingTransactionsIntentService" />
        <service android:name=".QueryService" />
        <service android:name=".LocationService" />
        <service android:name=".SignalService" />
        <service
            android:name=".SendOutstandingTransactions"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.carefreegroup.rr3.startatboot.MyService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>


        <receiver
            android:name="AlarmReceiver"
            android:process=":remote" >
        </receiver>


        <service
            android:name=".DeleteDuplicateTXTableService"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.carefreegroup.rr3.startatboot.DupTXService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="DuplicateTXReceiver"
            android:process=":remote" >
        </receiver>



         <service android:name=".EmailLog" />

        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />


        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
                  <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                    <category android:name="com.carefreegroup.rr3" />
                  </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


    </application>
```

Comment: One would imagine that your manifest has more than just that element. That element would not preclude Android 2.3.6 devices from seeing your app, but other elements in your manifest might.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've posted my full manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NFC was added in API Level 10. More importantly, few API Level 10 and below devices have NFC hardware. You are requiring that devices have NFC hardware; ergo, you will not have very many API Level 10 and below devices that support your app.

If you do not absolutely need NFC to function, use `android:required="false"`, and check for NFC availability at runtime, either via `PackageManager` and `hasSystemFeature()`, or just whether you can get your `NfcAdapter`.

In addition:

- You will only be available for devices that have Maps V1, and I would imagine that some newer devices will start dropping support for that, since Maps V1 has been deprecated for a year.
- You are wasting CPU and memory with those `:remote` receivers
- There is no `PREVENT_POWER_KEY` permission in Android

Comment: ok thanks alot. My app gathers information that makes a transaction from 2 sources, NFC tag or QR code. Some companies have bought NFC phones the others use the camera to scan a QR code. Would i need to check at runtime the NFC availability? The NFC part of the app only executes when an NFC intent is found from a tag. this means the non-nfc phones would never enter into this part of the code.

Comment: @turtleboy: Your analysis seems sound. If you are not initiating NFC communications (e.g., push, Android Beam), then you can probably get away without checking for NFC availability at runtime. You will still need to make NFC be not required in the manifest, though.